# package.json file invisible in explorer visual code

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, node-modules

When I create a package.json that file does not appear in explorer which concern to visual code. So, what's the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `Open Folder` button?

Answer (score 0):

You have opened only one file in the VSC. From the top select *File -> Open Folder...* or use the shortcut *Ctrl+K Ctrl+O* and then select the folder of which contents you want to be displayed in the editor. When no folders are opened you can also select the *Open Folder* button to directly select and open a folder. 
For example, in this case, open the folder the package.json is in, after which all the contents of that folder will be displayed in the *Explorer tab* (*Ctrl+Shift+E*).

Note that opening a new folder may close any opened files so save before doing anything.

If you only want to see only one file at a time, you can select *File -> Open file...* instead.